# Angular2 Material & angular2-color-picker error

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using angular2 with the new angular-material and third party directive angular2-color-picker throws error:

```
"can't bind to 'colorPicker' since it isn't a known property"
```

Answer (score 0):

in NgModule  imports sections: ColorPickerModule must be included before MaterialModule. That does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In your base module file (app.module.ts or similar) add below line

```
import {ColorPickerModule} from 'angular2-color-picker';
```

In the same file inside your NgModule add ColorPickerModule section do like this. this will work.

import {ColorPickerModule} from 'angular2-color-picker';

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ColorPickerModule,
    .........,
    .........
  ],
  declarations: [
    ........,
    ........
  ],
  providers: [
    ........,
    .........
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try importing it in app.module.ts

```
import {...} from '..';
import {ColorPickerModule} from 'angular2-color-picker'; //SEE THIS


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ColorPickerModule,//SEE THIS
        ...
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks, I have updated my answer, hopes this helps to solve the problem